# Exporting and importing Dell iDRAC 9 configurations

Tags: dell-poweredge, export, import

I would like to get configuration from Dell iDRAC 9 and save it somewhere. So that new similar hardware can be configured remotely and automatically.

I was able to get some configurations via `racadm.exe` as XML file but could not import it to another system.

Or is there any other way that I can solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please detail the problem you're encontering when importing the profile ? Also, have a look at this whitepaper that covers import/export of XML server profile http://en.community.dell.com/cfs-file/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/13-4491-00-00-20-26-95-86/Configuration-XML-Workflows.pdf

Comment: If you don't plan to use an automatoed process to collect/deploy XML profile of some sort, I would suggest looking at OpenManage Enterprise (or OpenManage Essential) to do that but the feature you're looking at requires a idrac license.

Comment: Idrac license is not the problem in this case. We wish to use an automated process thats why we plan to do it. In the mean time I was able to do somethings.it looks like this                                                                                       `racadm -r <IP Idrac> -u root -p <password of Idrac> get -f <location to place CSP> -t xml --clone` to download config as xml and `racadm -r <IP Idrac> -u root -p <password of Idrac> set -f <SCP file to be uploaded> -t xml` to upload correct config. This requieres same hardware to be same/similar

Comment: This is what `-clone` is ment for: an exact clone for the source host to the new host (in case the original host has failed for example). If you just need to get a template to propagate some setting to other hosts, do not use clone option. Also, keep in mind that you can edit the XML file and just keep the specific settings you want to deploy on new servers.